# Recursive grammar with increasing integers

Tags: recursion, grammar, context-sensitive-grammar

I want to write the grammar for a list containing sequentially increasing integers like this

```
1 X
1 X 2 X
1 X 2 X 3 X
1 X 2 X 3 X 4 X
// and so on
```

I want to use a recursive definition to avoid defining separate rules for each case manually.

Without the increasing integers, I could write the following recursive grammar (in McKeeman Form)

```
NumberedList
    Int X
    Int X NumberedList
```

How can I specify the increasing integers?

Answer (score 2):

No context-free grammar can represent this language because it is not context-free. Each expansion depends on the preceding expansion, which is an example of what the "context" in "context-free" is referring to.

It would be straightforward but tedious to write a context-sensitive grammar. That's the result of having to write out decimal arithmetic as a set of string substitution rules.

Comment: Thank you! Can you point me towards the way how I’d start writing this in a context-sensitive grammar?

Comment: @philmcole: to what end? Writing CSGs is like writing Turing Machines; possibly an interesting intellectual exercise although highly repetitive, bit of very little practical use.

Comment: @philmcole It would be much simpler to just use a context-free grammar, and if implementing the language add semantic checks to enforce the increasing numbers.